# How do I fix CORS Error when Trying to fetch data from SERP API into my react app

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

I am trying to fetch data from SERP API to fetch Job_Results, on postman, I am able to fetch my data but when I try to fetch it using Axios, I get CORS Error even after specifying Proxy in package.json and passing appropriate headers.

This is my code snippet:

```
let config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
    };
    const data = await axios.get(
      "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_jobs&q=internship+new+delhi&hl=en&api_key=xxxxxx",
      config
    );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: No, Actually most of the solutions I found only included either passing the header, or do some changes in node js backend which is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per this https://forum.serpapi.com/feature-requests/p/add-http-cors-headers
serpapi doesn't allow cross-origin requests from the browsers

So you need to use this in Server side code only, You cannot consume this API in React or any frontend application

For example To get
[https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_jobs&q=internship+new+delhi&hl=en&api_key=xxxxxx"](https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_jobs&q=internship+new+delhi&hl=en&api_key=xxxxxx%22)

You need to create a endpoint in server side
yourdomain.com/requiredparams that takes params and pass to https://serpapi.com/search.json and request data

So instead of calling serpapi you call your own API and Server will make request to serpapi and give response
If you follow this way your API key is also safe

Comment: I work at SerpApi and can confirm this answer is correct, with the caveat that you may need to add security features to have your API key be truly safe. I also wrote a blog post explaining how to create a Node.js server for connecting a front end application to SerpApi: https://serpapi.com/blog/adding-a-node-js-backend-to-handle-api-interactions-for-a-frontend-application/